# Simple design: tight horizontal form rows in Boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm not at all good with design, and am just trying to get a simple form alignment going in Bootstrap 4; I'm not doing anything custom at all, just happy to go with whatever the framework gives me.

I've read through the form documentation, and the number of variants is very confusing, and so far everything I've tried has failed in some way.

I have a form with multiple rows, with each row consisting of three elements: A label; a textfield that should have size=60 (although I guess this could just be an approximation); and a select list. That's it. I don't want any extra space between these elements, so using the grid system wouldn't seem to be the right solution.

The closest thing I came up with was this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-auto col-form-label"><label for="dishes-0-dish">Dish</label></div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <input class="form-control" id="dishes-0-dish" name="dishes-0-dish" size="60" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <select id="dishes-0-type" name="dishes-0-type"><option value="13">Cheese</option><option value="6">Dessert</option><option value="3">Fish</option><option value="12">Meat</option></select>
    </div>
</div>

[the above is repeated five times, with different index numbers]

<div>
    <input class="btn" value="Add" name="choice" type="submit" />
</div>
</div>
```

However, the label appears too high, aligned with the top of the text field, and appears to extend too low (if I add another class to have the label appear on a different-color background). Similarly the select box is also aligned with the top of the text field, and only takes up half of the vertical space of the text field. And the "Add" button isn't aligned with anything.

How should I properly style this? Thanks.

Edit: the way this looks for me in Chrome is

[image: (sample image)]

Which shows the poor vertical alignment, and the unaligned submit button. I can't really show an image of what I *do* want, because I'm not a designer; again, I'm happy with some generic design that doesn't have any obvious flaws, as this one does.

Edit again: This has the `form-control` as suggested, which fixed the alignment of the select and the enter button (thanks!), and with `col` instead of `col-auto` on the text and select fields. However, now the select field is far too long.

[image: (revised image)]

If I put `col-auto` on the select, then it is a reasonable size, but the textfield is gigantic (not the 60 I specify). Going back to `col-auto` on both is reasonable, and I might just stay here.

[image: (another revised image)].

For both of these, I've backed out the other CSS apart from the yellow background and some generic font stuff; there's nothing else related to alignment. Now the label looks dull as hell; is it the case that generic labels in Bootstrap have such little styling? In any case, I think most of the issues are solved; thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're looking for. Do you want less vertical space between the rows or horizontal space between the col-auto? Also, the select should be `form-control` if you want it to align with the other label/inputs.

Comment: After moving the content into a snippet, the label looks like it is aligned properly to the center of the text-box?

Comment: If possible, could you provide a simple image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: As I said, "the select should be form-control if you want it to align with the other label/inputs". It looks like you have other CSS. Can you post *all* of the relevant code?

Comment: I've added more images for other examples. The form-control works great, and I think I'm pretty much where I want, or at least where I can be satisfied. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `col-auto` on the label, it will fit the column to the label size and then if you just have `col` for the other two inputs, then they will be evenly sized on the same line. I also cancelled out the `margin-bottom` that gets automatically applied to the label and added `vertical-align:middle;` to align it with the other inputs.

```css
label{
  margin-bottom:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-auto col-form-label"><label for="dishes-0-dish">Dish</label></div>
    <div class="col">
        <input class="form-control" id="dishes-0-dish" name="dishes-0-dish" size="60" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <select id="dishes-0-type" name="dishes-0-type" class="form-control"><option value="13">Cheese</option><option value="6">Dessert</option><option value="3">Fish</option><option value="12">Meat</option></select>
    </div>
</div>

[the above is repeated five times, with different index numbers]

<div>
    <input class="btn" value="Add" name="choice" type="submit" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added a picture showing the current problem. Changing "col-auto" to "col" on the second two fields does make them shrink a bit, which is indeed better; I can't tell what else it's supposed to do, but it's certainly an improvement. I still have the vertical alignment problems, though.

Comment: @user1235777 I've edited my answer. Bootstrap automatically adds a margin to the bottom of the label, so I removed that, then added `vertical-align:middle;` to align it to the middle of the other inputs.